# Displaying loading image in center of specific html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have image tag which has id attribute. I want to show this loading image in center of specific html form(i have id of that html form). i am using jquery. i am not sure how to go for this?

```
 <img id="loading" src="loading.gif" />
```

the reason to do this i can have multiple forms inside a single page. i want to show the image in center of a particular  form boundary not complete page boundary

Comment: Try adding  #loading {width: 200px; margin-left: 50%; margin-top: 50%;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need these jQuery methods:

- `offset()`
- `width()`
- `height()`

Some math and you can easily center the element on the form.
Notice that forms have a default width of 100%.

Check my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/3pbkV/

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this...

```
$('#form-id').submit(
  function(e) {
    $(this).children().hide();
    $(this).append('<img id="loading" src="loading.gif" />');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

With come CSS we come to this very basic structure (put this HTML inside a form and add CSS to style overlay)

```
<div class="loader">
    <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/duesseldorf/32/process.png">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aG3DP/

Answer (score 0):

You should probably wrap the form inside a DIV, then just place the `img` with margins so it is displayed in the center of the DIV (Containing your form)

```
img#loading {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

You might want to hide it by default using javascript or something.

EDIT:
With regards to your existing content inside of your form, I would specify the position of the  image with `position:absolute;`.

Comment: Chances are the form already has lots of content, and he wants the loader to be positioned on top of the content

Comment: @Andy Right-o, then I see no good way but to specify the location with position:absolute

Answer (score 0):

If you use `position:absolute;` to position your loader in the center of your form, remember to use `position: relative;` on your form, since absolute positioned elements are positioned relative to their first positioned parent element.

Example: 
HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
    <div class="loader"><img src="loading.gif"></div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form#myform {
    position: relative;
}
div.loader {
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -30px;
   margin-left: -30px;
   display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $('form#myform').submit(function() {
      $(this).find('.loader').show();
   });
});
```